# How to install VSCODE on debian 9? Nothing works

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install Visual studio code.

My Raspb. Version is:

Distributor ID: Raspbian

Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)

Release:    9.8

Codename:   stretch

I tried several method (starting to download .deb and using dpkg or install command) but nothing worked.

How can I fix this problem? I really need VSC because my project is growing and Geany messes up.

Downloaded .deb and .tar files from the official site, followed the setup instruction but I got this error

With dpkg (both 32 and 64bit):

```
"package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)"

"package architecture (i386) does not match system (armhf)"
```

With sudo install:

```
sudo apt install ./code_1.33.1-1554971066_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'code:amd64' instead of './code_1.33.1-1554971066_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code:amd64 : Depends: libnotify4:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.26) but it is not installable
              Depends: apt:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libxkbfile1:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libsecret-1-0:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxss1:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

With repository:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Err:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
  Could not resolve host: packages.microsoft.com
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve host: packages.microsoft.com
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get install code
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package code
```

I'm getting mad about this problem, I tried older repository but they don't work.

Comment: The third code block looks like you have no internet connection. Also, you're trying to install a package in architecture x386 or amd64, but a Raspberry Pi has an ARM architecture, so these packages will never work.

Comment: Internet works and i thought the same thing about arm and amd. I mean, they have totally different architecture but the VSC site give that package for debian system that we all know are installed on RPi. I don't understand why they give an amd package.

Comment: @Giulio: Because Debian is also used on regular desktop systems (i.e. x86 or amd64). In addition probably most of the users would install VSCode on a Debian desktop system, but not on a Raspi, because of limited hardware performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [Community builds of Visual Studio Code](https://code.headmelted.com/) available (for Raspberry Pi and other ARM and Intel systems).

The packages are currently available in DEB and RPM format. You can use the scripts provided [here](https://code.headmelted.com/) to install the packages and add their repository to your system or install it manually.

Below I summarized the steps:

---

> Open a new terminal. If you need super-user rights (you probably do), then you can enter `sudo -s` and press return to enter a super-user session. Run the installer for your current distribution:
>
> #### APT instructions
>
> *(including Debian, Raspbian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint)*
>
> ```
> . <( wget -O - https://code.headmelted.com/installers/apt.sh )
> ```
>
> Press the return key. Once the installer has completed, you should have a "Code - OSS" entry in your desktop program list.
>
> #### Manual installation
>
> If for any reason the script above will not work on your system, or you do not want to add the package source for updates, you can get the latest version of the package for your system below.
>
> #### Public GPG key
>
> For either APT or YUM installation, you'll want the public GPG key to verify the package, which you can download [here](https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds/gpgkey).
>
> #### APT and YUM packages
>
> The latest packages are available directly from the [PackageCloud releases page](https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds).

The specific package you need is available [here](https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds/packages/debian/stretch/code-oss_1.32.0-1550644722_armhf.deb).

---

## EDIT:

At this time (29.04.2019) the current release (v. 1.32) appears **not** to be working for everybody. See: [issue#64](https://github.com/headmelted/codebuilds/issues/67). Seems that you'll have to [go back to v. 1.29](https://github.com/headmelted/codebuilds/issues/67#issuecomment-466132534), which is reported to be running fine.

You can choose [this package](https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds/packages/debian/stretch/code-oss_1.29.0-1539702286_armhf.deb) and install it manually, or use APT. If you decide to install it via APT, note that you'll have to mark the package `on hold` as described below.

To prevent `code-oss` from upgrading (so that you can keep v. 1.29 until the issue is fixed) follow [these instructions](https://github.com/headmelted/codebuilds/issues/67#issuecomment-466255567):

> Install v. 1.29 via APT:
>
> ```
> apt-get install code-oss=1.29.0-1539702286
> ```
>
> Then mark it *on hold* by running:
>
> ```
> apt-mark hold code-oss
> ```
>
> Now running `apt-get upgrade` won't try to bump it up until you run:
>
> ```
> apt-mark unhold code-oss
> ```
>
> This will allow it to upgrade again as usual.

Comment: I could install all package but when I open CODE-OSS it is only a black page. It doesent load nothing (even after 5min).

Comment: @Giulio Seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/headmelted/codebuilds/issues/64). The current release (v. 1.32) clearly isn't working on RPi. But going back to (or installing) v. 1.29 should work, see [this comment](https://github.com/headmelted/codebuilds/issues/67#issuecomment-466132534) and [this workaround](https://github.com/headmelted/codebuilds/issues/67#issuecomment-466255567). Hope this works for you. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Woow it worked... "I love" this kind of error.
Thank you !!